# Permanent FTP access for user?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, ftp

I've set up my VPS with a second user `foo` using

`sudo adduser foo` and then given access `ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` using `sudo /usr/sbin/visudo`,

And then I can use this user to access the server's root directory via FTP- however, after a few hours, when I log back in to FTP with this user, I can only access the home directory for said user, and no longer have root access. Though, when I try to check the user's permissions, they are still listed as `ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

I even tried creating a new user in the same way- and the permissions for this new user are also restricted.

Answer (score 1):

This was a fairly annoying problem, however I managed to resolve by by simply switching over to SFTP- at least, for now. However, if anyone knows if this is an issue that persists, answers are welcome!